# Android: Datepicker inside a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, datepicker

I am building an android app and I am facing a problem with `DatePicker`.
My implementation (the way I want it to be) is as follows:
A `GridView` (with images) and on item selected start a new intent.
On a specific item, I want firstly to launch a `DatePicker` and on `DatePicker` selection, start the new intent. The problem is that or the `DatePicker` will launch later that it is supposed to, or it will not start at all.
If anyone could help, I would be thankful (about the code, or If he could provide me another more proper implementation-solution).

So I have this code inside the `onCreate()`:

```
gridview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        calendarDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        caseCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                if(position == 7){
                    onCustomDatePicker();
                    if(caseCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < calendarDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)){
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Πρέπει να επιλέξεις μεταγενέστερη ημερομηνία", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        onCustomDatePicker();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    caseCalendar = calendarDate;
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Customize.class);
                ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                DateWithImage temp = (DateWithImage) holder.image.getTag();
                intent.putExtra("image",temp.getImageID());
                intent.putExtra("option",position);
                intent.putExtra("info",temp.getInfo());
                intent.putExtra("calendar", calendarDate);
                intent.putExtra("caseCalendar", caseCalendar);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

and this code for the `DatePicker`:

```
private void onCustomDatePicker(){
    new DatePickerDialog(this, d, caseCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),caseCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),caseCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
}

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        caseCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        caseCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        caseCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
    }
};
```

I am trying to set the new date into the `caseCalendar` and compare it to the `calendarDate` (which holds the current date).

Answer (score 0):

you are calling  `startActivity(intent);` everytime you are going to click on an image . For specific items you need to write like this :

```
if(position == 7){
                    onCustomDatePicker();
                    if(caseCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < calendarDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)){
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Πρέπει να επιλέξεις μεταγενέστερη ημερομηνία", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        onCustomDatePicker();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    caseCalendar = calendarDate;
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Customize.class);
                ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                DateWithImage temp = (DateWithImage) holder.image.getTag();
                intent.putExtra("image",temp.getImageID());
                intent.putExtra("option",position);
                intent.putExtra("info",temp.getInfo());
                intent.putExtra("calendar", calendarDate);
                intent.putExtra("caseCalendar", caseCalendar);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + position,      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

First you need to call only datepicker dialog and then on date set you can start new activity . Right now you are starting activity at just image click only .

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't seem to work, although your implementation gave me some good hints. Unfortunately, or I will stuck with a datepicker or the new intent will pop up, before I get to choose.

Answer (score 0):

OK, So I finally found the solution, just in case someone encounters this problem (a datePicker, implemented inside a gridview.SetOnClickListener) -

To be honnest, although it is working, I would appreciate if someone could tell me, if this is a Good Programming Practic .... :

I have used two Calendars (one for the current day and one for the selected one - apparently if I initialize the caseCalendar with getInstance(), it gets the same value with the calendarDate ????? ):

```
calendarDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        caseCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(calendarDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendarDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) ,calendarDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)-1);
```

inside the onCreate():

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                final int mposition = position;
                if(mposition == 7){//in my case the desired position to trigger the dayPicker
                    if(caseCalendar.compareTo(calendarDate)< 0){
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        onCustomDatePicker(holder,mposition);
                     }
                }
                else{
                    caseCalendar = calendarDate;
                    startNewActivity(holder,mposition);
                }
            }
        });
```

On a single specific option, I want to get the datePicker before the new activity, but on the other options, I want to start the new activity immediately. So I have used these two methods:

```
private void onCustomDatePicker(final ViewHolder holder, final int mposition){
        new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                caseCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                caseCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                caseCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                startNewActivity(holder, mposition);
            }
        }, caseCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),caseCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),caseCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }

    private void startNewActivity(final ViewHolder holder, final int mposition){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Customize.class);
        DateWithImage temp = (DateWithImage) holder.image.getTag();
        intent.putExtra("image",temp.getImageID());
        intent.putExtra("option",mposition);
        intent.putExtra("info",temp.getInfo());
        intent.putExtra("calendar", calendarDate);
        intent.putExtra("caseCalendar", caseCalendar);
        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + mposition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```